# Oauth2 & Laravel - `Client_id` & `Client_secret` - where to place, store, call?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, oauth-2.0, lumen

I am using [OAuth-Server-Laravel repo docs](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/wiki/Implementing-an-Authorization-Server-with-the-Password-Grant) and I am using Lumen. I have successfully made work Client Credentials grant type and trying to move it to Password grant type.

I added the PasswordVerifier class with `verify()` function, changed my database `oauth_clients` table to:

```
        $table->string('id', 40)->primary();
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['id', 'username']);
```

and `verify()` function as:

```
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
```

When I try it in Postman, I receive:

`"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"client_id\" parameter."`

Then I read in the issues and found out that I need to import `client_id` and `client_secret` beside `username` and `password` credentials. I understand these are something I should define.

But, I couldn't figure out where to place them, store them and call them? Should I store them in `.env` file? If so, how am I supposed to call it in the verify function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an `oauth_clients` table created by that package.  This defines what clients have access to make API calls to your resource server.  Your authorization server verifies these clients exist in this table and the secrets match whenever requests are made from a client.

The structure of that table is like this:

```
id (primary)
secret
name
created_at
updated_at
```

Each entry in this table represents a single client-side *application* that has some sort of access to your API.

Comment: I deleted the stuff inside `oauth_clients` and I added username, password, email stuff in there. But, I should've the structure of `oauth_clients` should be left as it was, where should I put my username, password stuff?

Comment: In a separate `users` table. Those are _users_ and not _clients_

Comment: Oh. But how am I supposed to call `client id` and `client_secret` in the `verify()` function and compare it to client_id and client_secret in the database? Username and password are going to come from a post request, but client_id and client_secret? I couldn't fully understand the logic.

Comment: You don't verify the `client_id` and `client_secret`.  The package provides that functionality for you in a middleware (filter for laravel 4) as well as each of the different grant types `completeFlow` functions.

Comment: When I try to post into that route, it forces me to include `client_id` and `client_secret`. If I don't submit these two values, it fails. I got so confused. Do I need to place client_id and client_secret in the html and post them while I'm posting username, password variables? I know that doesn't make sense but I couldn't figure out any other way

Comment: Each app you write which consumes your API is going to have a static client id and secret. These are like a username / password pair for your applications, and you should try to keep them secret, so no, I wouldn't put them in the HTML. Most places I've seen have a server-side client that uses Guzzle or cURL to proxy API requests through their application to prevent leaking the id/secret out

Comment: So, while proceeding username/password login, first I need to submit the `username` and `password` credentials to validation function. And in validation function, before validating user credentials, first I need to use Guzzle to make another call (to another route) to validate `client_id` and `client_secret` separately (to receive `access_token`), and then if success I continue on validating user credentials. Is that approach correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94635/discussion-between-watcher-and-senty).